# Check two words to see if the beginning of word a is equal to word b

Tags: java, compare, substring

Given the following strings

```
String a = "hello";
String b = "hell";
String c = "help";
```

I would like to find out if string b is a substring of a, and if string c is a substring of a.

You can see here the answer is clearly yes for b and no for c.
How can I perform this test in Java?

Answer (score 2):

Very simple:

```
if (a.startsWith(b))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if(a.contains(b)) {...}
if(a.contains(c)) {...}
```

works also with:

```
if(a.contains("ell")) {...}
```

Comment: If a equals hello and b equals ello this would return true. He wants the beginning, not any index.

Comment: @Legend: not sure what OP wants, but the second answer of *SLaks* completes the question.

Comment: "Check two words to see if the beginning of word a is equal to word b"

Comment: @Legend you are right, I missed the title, contents only say about *substring*. +1 to you and SLaks